# Are these R-homomorphisms necessary in this argument?

Tags: modules, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

I just started to learn some multilinear algebra, that I lacked in my undergraduate program. I decided to do it with the book of Douglas Northcott.

He defines what is going to be the solution for the universal problem for multilinear mappings.

Given $R$ a commutative non-trivial ring which possesses an identity element, let $p\in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$ and $M_1,\dotsc,M_p$ be $R$-modules, he denotes $U(M_1,\dotsc,M_p)$ as the free ring generated by the cartesian product $M_1\times\dotsb\times M_p$.

The elements of $U(M_1,\dotsc,M_p)$ that have one of the following forms
$$(m_1,\dotsc,m_i+m_i',\dotsc,m_p)-(m_1,\dotsc,m_i,\dotsc,m_p)-(m_1,\dotsc,m_i',\cdots,m_p)$$
or
$$(m_1,\dotsc,rm_i,\dotsc,m_p)-r(m_1,\dotsc,m_i,\dotsc,m_p)$$
generate a submodule that he denotes as $V(M_1,\dotsc,M_p)$. Then he does $M:=U(M_1,\dotsc,M_p)/V(M_1,\dotsc,M_p)$ and defines the mapping $\phi:M_1\times\dotsb\times M_p\rightarrow M$ by letting $\phi(m_1,\dotsc,m_p)$ is the natural image of $(m_1,\dotsc,m_p)$ considered as an element of $U(M_1,\dotsc,M_p)$ in M. Since the elements that generate $V(M_1,\dotsc,M_p)$ become zero in M, $\phi$ is multilinear.

Then he goes onto proving that the universal problem for multilinear mappings has unique solution up to isomorphism. But then as a corollary he says that each element of $M$ can be expressed as a finite sum of elements of the form $\phi(m_1,\dotsc,m_p)$.

This is where the confusion to me lays, in his proof,

Suppose that $M'$ is the $R$-submodule of $M$ generated by elements of the form $\phi(m_1,\dotsc,m_p)$. Also let $h_1:M\rightarrow M/M'$ be the natural homomorphism and $h_2:M\rightarrow M/M'$ be the null homomorphism. Then $h_1\circ\phi=h_2\circ\phi$ and therefore $h_1=h_2$. However, this implies that $M=M'$.

The proof continues but here I have the problem that I don't see why is the case that $h_1\circ\phi=h_2\circ\phi$, but when I somehow see it is when I think that they have the same image for every element, but I think I am wrong in this, but if I am not then almost everything seems unnecessary as by construction then you have that $M=M'$, which is part of what he is trying to prove. I get the feeling that the kind of argument that he does is very common in homological algebra (maybe not, right now I am complete ignorant of that field).

I am sorry if this is very low level for the site, I feel kind of embarassed as I have been stucked in this for two days.

Comment: I completely agree, $h_1\circ\phi=h_2\circ\phi$ because (clearly) "they have the same image for every element", and this proof seems indeed unnecessary as $M=M'$ by construction.

Comment: @AnneBauval don't get me wrong, I don't mean to be rude, but your answer seems like you are trolling me, because it doesn't help at all.

Comment: I did my best though. What more do you want? In clear: imo the book is wrong  (I feel sorry you are forcing me to say this with no disguise)  and you are right.

Comment: @AnneBauval well in that case, I feel sorry for my response and thank you for taking the time to answer. Also could I have some recommendation for a good book to learn about tensor products, tensor algebras and related things? My background is that I have done some courses in ring theory and group theory, although I'm bad at groups (I want to improve). I want to learn this to be able to understand it and used it in very different ambients, from Stokes's generalized theorem (I don't like the version of this that was given to me) and homological algebra to some continuum mechanics.

Comment: I know that group theory gets in the way for me to learning homological algebra, so if I could use another recommendation, I would be very grateful for that.